# Обновить значения в массиве, на основе другого существующего

Tags: javascript

Нужно пройтись по массиву zones и заполнить свойство active_zones на основе allZones. Т.е. в итоге active_zones = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

```
const allZones = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const zones = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: "key",
    label: "Ключ",
    value: 12345,
    active_zones: [1, 2, 5]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "key",
    label: "Ключ",
    value: 12345,
    active_zones: [1, 2, 5]
  }
];
```

Comment: `zones.forEach(zone => zone.active_zones = allZones)` не подойдёт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const allZones = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const zones = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: "key",
    label: "Ключ",
    value: 12345,
    active_zones: [1, 2, 5]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "key",
    label: "Ключ",
    value: 12345,
    active_zones: [1, 2, 5]
  }
];

zones.forEach(item => {
  item.active_zones = Array.from(allZones)
})

console.log(zones)
```

Comment: Если бы Вы еще тут указали, чем этот вариант принципиально отличается от приведенного мной в комментарии к вопросу, было бы совсем хорошо. :)

Comment: Я не читал ваш комментарий

Comment: А. Ну все равно, о разнице этих вариантов было бы полезно добавить пару слов. :)

Comment: Разница в том, что вариант в этом ответе присваивает новые независимые  копии, а вариант в комментарии - ссылки на один и тот же массив и изменения в этом массиве будут затрагивать все ссылки на него.